# How to select results of text array type in mybatis?

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

For example, there is a table, which has a column of type `text[]`, in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id integer,
    name text,
    tags text[],
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Now, I want to select `tags` in two ways:

1. Select `tags` using primary key `id`, and the result should be of type `List<String>`
2. Select `tags` using `name`, and the result should be of type `List<List<String>>`

How should I write MyBatis mapper to achieve this?

Comment: This maay be helpful, http://beerholder.blogspot.com/2007/10/mapping-postgresql-arrays-with-ibatis-i.html

Comment: @GrootC I know how to handle it when the result is an user defined object, for a type handler can be used in resultMap. But when the result is `List<String>` or `List<List<String>>`, rather than a property of an object, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Java mapper, however, MyBatis internally calls `SqlSession#selectList` when the return type is `List` and that is not what you want.
So, you need to use `Object` as the return type instead.

```java
@Select("select tags from t where id = #{id}")
Object getTagById(Integer id);

@Select("select tags from t where name = #{name}")
List<Object> getTagByName(String name);
```

And register your type handler globally in the config. i.e.

```xml
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler handler="xxx.yyy.ListArrayTypeHandler" />
</typeHandlers>
```

or

```
configuration.getTypeHandlerRegistry()
  .register(ListArrayTypeHandler.class);
```

For completeness, here is an example type handler implementation.

```java
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedJdbcTypes;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;

@MappedJdbcTypes({ JdbcType.ARRAY })
@MappedTypes({ Object.class })
public class ListArrayTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<List<?>> {

  @Override
  public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i,
      List<?> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    //  JDBC type is required
    Array array = ps.getConnection().createArrayOf("TEXT", parameter.toArray());
    try {
      ps.setArray(i, array);
    } finally {
      array.free();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public List<?> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    return extractArray(rs.getArray(columnName));
  }

  @Override
  public List<?> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return extractArray(rs.getArray(columnIndex));
  }

  @Override
  public List<?> getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return extractArray(cs.getArray(columnIndex));
  }

  protected List<?> extractArray(Array array) throws SQLException {
    if (array == null) {
      return null;
    }
    Object javaArray = array.getArray();
    array.free();
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList((Object[])javaArray));
  }
}
```

FYI, to store a `List` into the `tags` column, you may have to specify the type handler explicitly.

```sql
insert into t (...) values (#{id}, #{name},
  #{tags,typeHandler=xxx.yyy.ListArrayTypeHandler})
```

Comment: This workaround works just fine, though the flaw is that the return type is `Object`, which is a little ugly. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: As `List` is a special case in MyBatis, a certain degree of ugliness is unavoidable, I think.  
My personal recommendation is to declare `String[]` as the return type because 1) the default `ArrayTypeHandler` can handle it and 2) array-to-list conversion is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Sorry, using `String[]` as the return type does not work. I should've tested before adding a comment. 

Comment: I had to change @MappedTypes({ Object.class }) to @MappedTypes({ List.class }) to make this work for a list of strings (List<String>)

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first one with this issue.

The project [common-mybatis](https://github.com/gbif/common-mybatis/) has a type handler exactly for this use case: [StringArrayTypeHandler](https://github.com/gbif/common-mybatis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gbif/mybatis/type/StringArrayTypeHandler.java)

Just add it to the MyBatis configuration:

```xml
    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler handler="org.gbif.mybatis.type.StringArrayTypeHandler"/>
    </typeHandlers>
```

...and then for the mapping it is as simple as:

```xml
    <select id="getTagsById" resultType="java.util.List">
        SELECT tags FROM t WHERE id = #{id}
    </select>

    <select id="getTagsByName" resultType="java.util.List">
        SELECT tags FROM t WHERE name = #{name}
    </select>
```

...and in the code:

```java
try (SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
    List<String> tags = session.selectOne("[...].getTagsById", 1);
    System.out.println("Tags: " + tags);

    List<List<String>> multiTags = session.selectList("[...].getTagsByName", "test");
    System.out.println("Tags: " + multiTags);
}
```

Tested against a PostgreSQL 11 with JDBC driver version 42.2.5 and the following test data:

```sql
select * from t;
 id |  name   |                tags                
----+---------+------------------------------------
  1 | test    | {Thriller,Drama}
  2 | my name | {Science-Fiction,Adventure,Horror}
  3 | test    | {Comedy,Adventure}
(3 rows)
```

...produces:

```
Tags: [Thriller, Drama]
Tags: [[Thriller, Drama], [Comedy, Adventure]]
```

Comment: I don't know whether it's my mistake, but I tried this method and an exception was thrown. Could you paste the demo?

Comment: Revisited the situation and found a much simpler way. No `Object` needed here.